# Sample application for WiX bootstrapper for beginners

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, wix3.7

I'm very new to [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) based applications, and I need to create an [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) file where it has to check for [.NET Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) 4.0 and [SQL Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2008). If they are not installed, I have to get them installed first and then have to install my application's EXE file and one more [VBScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript) agent. It must be done like when you install WiX 3.7 setup (if we double click the setup file, it will show a UI as shown below!

[image: WiX Toolset installation UI]

Where do I start? Is there any step-by-step guide to develop this kind of application?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the following projects. They can be created from project templates in Visual Studio. Each of them would probably have separate tutorials that you might find with a Web search.

1. A WiX Setup project to build an .msi. The source files for such a project declare a WiX/Product. It could have conditions that check for .Net Framework4.0 and SQL Server 2008. If a check fails, installation of the .msi will fail, which is all that can be done in an .msi. The project would include your application .exe as a Component.
2. A WiX Bootstrapper project to build an .exe. The source files for such a project declare a WiX/Bundle. In the bundle is a Chain of installers, which would include .Net Framework4.0, SQL Server 2008, your .msi, and your VBScript Agent.
3. A WPF Library project to provide a BootstrapperApplication implementation with a custom UI for the bootstrapper project.

Your best bet is to consult the documentation, the WiX source code and various tutorials. Keep in the mind that tutorials might be out-of-date--in most cases WiX has gotten simpler with each version.

Comment: Thanx for your guidence, I have questions , Is WIX would be the best one for deployment or is there any other? In order to create an Custom UI , i got no idea, even if i go through web there are tutorials for WIX3.5  but not much for WIX3.7... Now i got an another challenge to include rdl files(Reports).. Please suggest some of the best links that you know. thanks again