# Dynamic and Static Resources graphical performance analysis

Tags: wpf, dynamic, static, analyzer, performancepoint

Is there any **graphical performance analysis** to see the performance difference between **Dynamic and Static Resources**.??

I go for Dynamic Resource when i need to change during run time, since in my project every styles has been predefined in Resource Dictionary,my people are referencing it as an Dynamic Resources..

I hope it can be referred as Static itself to improve the performance, when i browse for this ,maximum number of answer was said to use Static resource. Is it correct?? and i need performance graphical analyzer to see the difference.

Comment: Yes use StaticResources.

Comment: @devhedgehog , thanx for the reply, Is there any tool to see the performance difference??

Comment: DynamicResources are being called everytime you ask for the resource while StaticResources are only being called once. Does this answer your performance concerns. Btw premature optimization is the root of all evil so I suggest you just write your code and then optimize.

Comment: @devhedgehog, yep i understood the performance affect , but in order to show graphically to my Project lead i need some kind of tool. Is there any tool??:-)

Comment: Well all profiler tools show only measured results on your source code but we are talking here about microsoft inernal code so you will hardly find a tool that would filter you performance hit just on resources. If you are looking for a profiling tool just google free ones. There are few out there. I use RedGate but thats not free. Show your boss msdn link about those two. Somewhere there stands that StaticResources run faster.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613559.aspx See article use StaticResources if possible.

Comment: @devhedgehog, thanx for your efforts and by the way , i have shown many links reg this.. the key point is they need to talk to the client side(it looks wearied, but situation here is like this). thats'y after a long search for performance tool in .net,posted the ques:-) andalso could you guide me in this [**Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19321330/sample-application-for-wix-bootstrapper-for-begginers)